# Backbone model is saved but send an empty array to HTTP

Tags: javascript, http, rest, symfony, backbone.js

I have tried to solve a simple problem for several hours. I have a collection and here is my code:

```
var id = $(e.target).data("id");
var permissionModel = this.params.collection.get(id);
permissionModel.set({'permission_status':'active'});
permissionModel.save({
    success: function(data) {},
    error: function(data,jXHR) {}
});
```

And I have seen that the model is changed but I've got in my symfony controller:

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->request->all();
print_r($data);
die;
```

Result:

```
   array()
```

I don't understand why.
Can any one help me to find out the problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for the `Backbone.emulateJSON = true` settings.

Here is what the [official documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync-emulateJSON) has to say:

> If you're working with a legacy web server that can't handle requests
>   encoded as application/json, setting Backbone.emulateJSON = true; will
>   cause the JSON to be serialized under a model parameter, and the
>   request to be made with a application/x-www-form-urlencoded mime type,
>   as if from an HTML form.